# Google Geochart - same countries, different values

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I got some problems with displaying values for a country. The thing is, I want to display where football players of a certain team come from. Because many of them have same nationality, geochart displays only the last name in the array when hoovering over the country, but I want it to display all the names. 
This is the code:

```
var chart = function (item) {
  body = document.getElementById("regions_div");
  body.innerHTML = " ";
  var places = [];
  var names = [];
  for (var i = 0; i<item.length; i++) {
    person = item[i];
    country = person.nationality;
    name = person.name;
    places.push(country);
    names.push(name);
  };
  console.log(places);
  console.log(names);

  google.charts.load('upcoming', {'packages':['geochart']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);

  function drawRegionsMap() {

    var data = [];
    var header = ["Country", "Name"];
    data.push(header);
    for (var i = 0; i < places.length; i++) {
      var temp = [];
      temp.push(places[i]);
      temp.push(names[i]);
      console.log(temp);
      data.push(temp);
    }

    console.log(data);
    var chartdata = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(data);

    var options = {};

    var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('regions_div'));
    chart.draw(chartdata, options);
  }
}
```

And the screenshot, for example this time has multiple players from England but only the last one in the array is displayed :
[image: example]

Thanks for help!

Comment: ran into the same problem this week displaying students at universities -- had to build a custom tooltip -- use the [`group()` method](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#google_visualization_data_group) to group on country and build the tooltip for each row in the data -- if you can share a sample of the data (`item`), i can throw together an example...

Comment: @WhiteHat That would be great. Item is just a result from API, through which I get the names and countries. Final data for a team would be: 
`var places = ["Sam Johnstone", "Chris Smalling", "Phil Jones", "Luke Shaw"];`
`var names = ["United Kingdom",  "United Kingdom", "United Kingdom", "United Kingdom", ];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

following is an example of building a custom tooltip to show all names at each country

the `group()` method is used to group the names by country

then the tooltip is updated for each row in `chartdata`

for all the names found for each country

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawRegionsMap,
  packages:['geochart']
});

function drawRegionsMap() {
  var container = document.getElementById('regions_div');
  container.innerHTML = '';
  var names = ["Sam Johnstone", "Chris Smalling", "Phil Jones", "Luke Shaw"];
  var places = ["United Kingdom", "United Kingdom", "United Kingdom", "United Kingdom"];

  var data = [];
  var header = ["Country", "Name"];
  data.push(header);
  for (var i = 0; i < places.length; i++) {
    var temp = [];
    temp.push(places[i]);
    temp.push(names[i]);
    data.push(temp);
  }

  var chartdata = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(data);

  // group data by country, name
  var groupdata = google.visualization.data.group(
    chartdata,
    [0, 1],
    [{
      aggregation: google.visualization.data.count,
      column: 1,
      label: "Name",
      type: "number"
    }]
  );

  // update tooltip for each chart data row
  for (var i = 0; i < chartdata.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
    // find group rows for current country
    var locationRows = groupdata.getFilteredRows([{
      column: 0,
      value: chartdata.getValue(i, 0)
    }]);

    // build tooltip of all names for current country
    var nameTooltip = '';
    locationRows.forEach(function (index) {
      if (nameTooltip !== '') {
        nameTooltip += ', ';
      }
      nameTooltip += groupdata.getValue(index, 1);
    });

    // update tooltip
    chartdata.setValue(i, 1, nameTooltip);
  }

  var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(container);
  chart.draw(chartdata);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="regions_div"></div>
```

Comment: hope this helps, sorry took so long to respond -- pretty basic example but should get the point across...