# Google Geochart - same country multiple values from JSON data

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

Am trying to display all values for each country in a Google Geochart from data sent from my database (via JSON), but only the last row ever displays ('*Supplier 2*' in the case highlighted below). I have reviewed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41190424/google-geochart-same-countries-different-values) and attempted to incorporate the suggested [group() method](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#google_visualization_data_group); however this produces a console error which I am unable to successfully debug: '**unexpected token }**', which refers to the closing curly bracket in the *var groupData* declaration.

This is what currently shows, without using any group() method. I need '*Supplier 1*' to also display.

[image: example screenshot]

This is the code:

```
function incAvailableCountry() {
$.ajax({
    url: "inc-analysis/country-available.php,
    dataType: "json"
}).done(function(jsonData){
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);
    var groupData = google.visualization.data.group(
        data,
        [0, 1],
        [{
            aggregation: google.visualization.data.count,
            column, 0
        }]);
    var options = {
        width: 'auto',
        keepAspectRatio: true,
        legend: 'none'
    };

    for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
        var locationRows = groupData.getFilteredRows([{
            column: 0,
            value: data.getValue(i, 0)
        }]);
        var nameTooltip = '';
        locationRows.forEach(function(index){
            if (nameTooltip !== '') {
                nameTooltip += ', ';
            }
            nameTooltip += groupData.getValue(index, 1);
        });
        data.setValue(i, 1, nameTooltip);
    }

    var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('incAvailableCountry'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
});}
```

PHP:

```
<?php include '../core/init.php';

$query = mysqli_query($conn, "(SELECT Country, Supplier
    FROM table 
    GROUP BY Supplier)
    ORDER BY Country");

$table = array();
$table['cols'] = array(
    array('label' => 'Country', 'type' => 'string'),
    array('label' => 'Supplier', 'type' => 'string')
);

$rows = array();
while ($r1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $temp = array();
    $temp[] = array('v' => (string)$r1['Country']);
    $temp[] = array('v' => (string)$r1['Supplier']);
    $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
}

$table['rows'] = $rows;
$jsonTable = json_encode($table);
echo $jsonTable;
```

Resulting JSON:

```
{"cols":[
{"label":"Country","type":"string"},
{"label":"Supplier","type":"string"}],"rows":[
{"c":[{"v":"Spain"},
{"v":"Supplier 1"}]},
{"c":[{"v":"Spain"},
{"v":"Supplier 2"}]}]}
```

HTML:

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script>google.charts.load('current', {'packages': ['geochart'], 'mapsApiKey': 'key...'});</script>
<div id="incAvailableCountry"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the group method, `column` should be followed by a colon `:`, instead of a comma `,`

```
var groupData = google.visualization.data.group(
    data,
    [0, 1],
    [{
        aggregation: google.visualization.data.count,
        column, 0
    }]);
```

change to...

```
var groupData = google.visualization.data.group(
  data,
  [0, 1],
  [{
    aggregation: google.visualization.data.count,
    column: 0,
    type: 'number'
  }]
);
```